# How to Optimize MySQL (CentOS)

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, performance, caching

I have problems to optimize my VPS MySQL to use. I have a plan in RamNode with the following specs:

```
- Intel® Xeon® CPU E3-1240 V2 @ 3.40GHz (4 Cores)
- 4GB de Ram
- 135 GB SSD Raid 10
```

I have problems in one of the applications that I have hosted, slow, sometimes gives up error "max user connections".

Below the test conducted in MySQLTunner :

**Storage Engine Statistics**

```
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MYISAM
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 136M (Tables: 300)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 44M (Tables: 202)
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 17)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 220
```

**Performance Metrics**

```
[--] Up for: 1d 20h 25m 13s (3M q [23.681 qps], 251K conn, TX: 9B, RX: 605M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 57% / 43%
[--] Total buffers: 528.0M global + 3.6M per thread (400 max threads)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 7322
[!!] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 69% (144K temp sorts / 208K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 21719
```

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------

**General recommendations:**
Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance. Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries. Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes

**Variables to adjust:**

```
  query_cache_size (> 64M)
  sort_buffer_size (> 2M)
  read_rnd_buffer_size (> 236K)
  join_buffer_size (> 128.0K, or always use indexes with joins)
```

**Below My.CNF**

```
[mysqld]    
max_connections = 400    
max_user_connections=40    
key_buffer_size = 256M    
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 16M    
read_buffer_size = 1M
table_open_cache = 2048
thread_cache_size = 128
wait_timeout = 20
connect_timeout = 10
tmp_table_size = 128M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
max_allowed_packet=268435456
net_buffer_length = 5500
max_connect_errors = 10
concurrent_insert = 2
read_rnd_buffer_size = 242144
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 2M
query_cache_limit = 2M
query_cache_size = 64M
query_cache_type = 1
query_prealloc_size = 87382
query_alloc_block_size = 21845
transaction_alloc_block_size = 2730
transaction_prealloc_size = 1364
max_write_lock_count = 2
log-error
external-locking=FALSE
open_files_limit=15000
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
innodb_file_per_table=1
[mysqld_safe]

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 8M
[isamchk]
key_buffer = 128M
sort_buffer = 128M
read_buffer = 64M
write_buffer = 64M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 128M
sort_buffer = 128M
read_buffer = 64M
write_buffer = 64M 

#### Per connection configuration ####
sort_buffer_size = 2M
join_buffer_size = 2M
thread_stack = 192K
log-slow-queries
```

If you can help me thank you :)

Comment: It does not look good if you put your entire `mysqltuner` and `my.cnf` here. Only put relevant things that matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using a mixture of MyISAM and InnoDB tables. It would be best to settle on one or the other - almost certainly InnoDB is going to be better for optimisation purposes.

You should convert all tables in your solution to InnoDB. If your solution can create new tables, change the default-storage-engine type to InnoDB as well.

```
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
```

Then, since you have plenty of RAM, tune to ensure that all your data fits in RAM, so MySQL doesn't have to keep doing expensive disk reads all the time. Set innodb_buffer_pool_size to be at least 1G, maybe more if your database is going to grow rapidly. You can probably safely go up to 2G, so long as you don't have anything else that's really ram intensive running on this VPS.

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G
```

Currently you are running with the default InnoDB config options, which looks OK (144MB pool size, data size of only 44Mb), but you may as well configure for growth and take advantage of the RAM you have at your disposal. Also if you convert the 140Mb of MyISAM tables to InnoDB (recommended), then you really need this figure to be higher. This setting is probably *the* most important, and likely to make the biggest difference to performance.

Also, as you are hitting the max number of connections, you need to increase that value too. Your VPS should be able to handle more than the default of 40 - try anywhere between 50-100, depending on how many concurrent users/connections you expect.

```
max_user_connections=100
```

The stats also show that you have a large number of queries being executed without indexes

> [!!] Joins performed without indexes: 21719

This needs attention. If it's not obvious to work out which fields need indexing (normally any fields used in join statements, and some fields used for searching and filtering, especially if they are numeric and have only a limited selection of values), you can try running queries in your favourite mysql client, with the EXPLAIN statement. This will give you detailed information about which parts of the query are performing poorly.

See the Mysql manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html for more information.

It is always worth trying the addition of indexes to see whether they improve query performance. If they don't, remove them again, as indexes can make insert/update operations more expensive in terms of server resource (as the indexes need to be updated as well as the underlying data).

I highly recommend a MySQL GUI such as sqlyog for playing around with indexing. The MySQL client tools are also OK.

For more details see posts such as https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/ (a bit old but still talks sense).

If you have a compelling reason why you'd want to use MyISAM in preference to InnoDB (and I really can't think of one), then you would need different advice as the recommendations for innodb pool size are of no use to you.

Comment: My Dabase is only 200MB !

Comment: Sure, but it's going to keep growing. You have plenty of RAM so why not start with an InnoDB buffer size of 1G. It doesn't get used unless its needed. You're just future proofing your config.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't convert your MyISAM tables to InnoDB?

Comment: Also realised you may have indexing issues, so I've added some advice to my answer!

Comment: OK, I will convert all tables to InnoDB

Comment: It can be a bit trial and error unless you are really deep into it. Best thing is to add some indexes that look like they might help. If they don't, just remove them again!

The only time when this approach can backfire is if you have enormous tables in production, when even creating the index can cause an entire system to crawl or even crash.

Answer (score 0):

> Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance.

That's bogus advice.  It is almost never useful, especially for InnoDB.

2G for the buffer pool is dangerously large for a tiny 4GB system, especially while you have MyISAM tables in use.

While you have a mixture:

```
key_buffer_size = 200M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 500M
```

After you switch to InnoDB:

```
key_buffer_size = 30M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1000M
```

*Swapping* is much worse than lowering a value.

See [my tips on converting from MyISAM to InnoDB](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb).

The Query cache is doing a lot of prunes.  *Every* write to a table forces a prune of *all* entries for that table.  In general, the QC should be turned off for production servers.  Raising the size above 64M would make things worse.

```
max_user_connections=40
```

Is one "user" connecting more than 40 times at once?  Or do you have Apache with MaxClients > 40?

Show us a couple of your slow queries, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; we may be able to speed them up.

Comment: I've had good results with an innodb buffer pool size of 2GB on a 4GB system, otherwise I wouldn't have recommended it. However, we don't know what else is running on the VPS in this case, so yes keeping it at 1GB is a safer choice.

All the advice I have ever received or read is that you can safely set this value to about 75% of the machine's available RAM.

Also note that my advice was to convert the MyISAM tables to InnoDB.

Comment: I was afraid there were other apps in the 4GB.  Anyway, the dataset will probably be under 500M even after converting to InnoDB.  Note 75% of **available** RAM.